# Init a UInavigationbar

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am having trouble in making a tableview with navigation bar or controller on top.

I have this piece of code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationController *addNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Welcome" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;




    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

    NSString *documentDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"notebook.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.Notes = tmpArray;
    [tmpArray release];



}
```

However, the navigation bar never show up, while the table is doing fine. May i know what's the problem with the code?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an instance of `UINavigationController` but never added it to anything. You need to add it to the current hierarchy or it will not appear.

If you wish to add the navController to the entire app, then you should do this in the App Delegate by

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application

{

    UIViewController *rootController = [[MyRootViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]

                                initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    [rootController release];



    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Comment: But what if i dont want to add it to the entire app? What if i just want it appear in one view of the app? I tried to put them in viewDidLoad, but doesn't work. Thanks